Flutter Null Context
I'm getting the following message when trying to display a message to the user
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2794)
#1      showDialog (package:flutter/src/material/dialog.dart:1425)
#2      MyAppState.showMessage (package:simple_sensor_test/main.dart:45)
#3      MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:simple_sensor_test/main.dart:30)
#4      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1170)
#5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:351)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:656)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:313)
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:246)
#9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:703)
#10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/g<…>

The full program which shows the message is
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Testing'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row( // need upright vector, new lat, new lon
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () { showMessage("Hello", "world"); },
                    child: const Text('Calculate'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showMessage(String title, String message) async {
    // Ensure the widget is still mounted and context is valid
    if (mounted) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) =>
              const Center(
                child: Material(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Text('Message'),
                ),
              )
      );
    }
  }
}

I assume that the context is inherited from the State object: however when it gets to the Navigator function, it's obviously not set. Any ideas, anyone? How do I pass the context into the showDialog function?

are you calling it directly inside MaterialApp route context?

where are you calling the showMessage function from

The message is called as a result of a focus change - I'm using this to detect errors in an input text field.

The stack trace shows that showMessage is being called from valueChange in your code which isn’t in the code provided. I suspect that the issue is being caused by code that we don’t know about.

The code that you provided is perfectly functional. What’s more, it’s not possible for the State.context getter to return null, because if the context internally was null then the getter would throw a FlutterError instead of returning null. The cause of your issue must be in code that you eliminated when you were refactoring for your question.

The issue is somewhere else in your code.

I've updated the stack trace to show the results of the program you see above. The error is definitely in the code you can see, as there isn't any more code.

The issue isn't that context is null, because as I've said in comments, that's not possible. The issue is that the context you are sending to showDialog doesn’t have a Navigator ancestor. This is because the Navigator is coming from the MaterialApp that is a child of this widget, so it can’t be found using this widget’s context. That’s causing the Navigator.of call within showDialog to throw the error you are seeing.
You need to take the body of MaterialApp and make it into its own widget, and then that widget’s context will have a MaterialApp (and therefore a Navigator) in its ancestry.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Testing'),
        ),
        body: MyAppHome(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppHomeState createState() => MyAppHomeState();
}

class MyAppHomeState extends State<MyAppHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row( // need upright vector, new lat, new lon
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () { showMessage("Hello", "world"); },
                child: const Text('Calculate'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showMessage(String title, String message) async {
    // Ensure the widget is still mounted and context is valid
    if (mounted) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) =>
              const Center(
                child: Material(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Text('Message'),
                ),
              )
      );
    }
  }
}


Thank you - that's exactly the answer I was looking for: you've explained perfectly why my code didn't work, why I need an intervening StatelessWidget (which I didn't understand before) and improved my knowledge as a result.

Navigator.of(context) must be called at MaterialApp or Navigator tree. Check showMessage function is it in the right context.

I suspect you're correct in that the showMessage function isn't called in the correct context. It's called when a text field loses focus and contains invalid input. The text field is instantiated from within a MaterialApp tree, but the focus controller isn't - I'll change it to see if that fixes the problem.

Didn't manage to instantiate the focus handlers in the Material App tree, but the error still exists in the complete example above.
